# The equivalent of `syncWithPivotValues` for `attach` method in Laravel 9

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship, laravel-9

In Laravel 9, there's `syncWithPivotValues`, which can sync several records with passed pivot values. Is there such thing for `attach` method? Basically I want to perform `attach` to several records with the same pivot values, such as:

```php
// attach `role` 1, 2, 3 to `$user`; with `active` attribute set to `true`
$user->roles()->attach([1, 2, 3], ['active' => true]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```php
$user->roles()->attach([
    1 => ['active' => true],
    2 => ['active' => true],
    3 => ['active' => true],
]);
```

Resource: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships

If you don't want to repeat `['active' => true]` all the time, you can use `array_fill_keys` like this: `array_fill_keys([1, 2, 3], ['active' => true])` so your code will look like:

```php
$user->roles()->attach(array_fill_keys([1, 2, 3], ['active' => true]));
```

Resource: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill-keys.php

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but my point is that I don't want to write the `'active' => true` 3 times. Is that possible?

Comment: @rifqyabdl I updated my answer so it is shorter now. Unfortunately you can't do that what you want, but you can use some trickery to achieve the same.